# Why the Input autocomplete="on" is not working in Mozilla Firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, input, mozilla

I have the input field with autocomplete="on" as shown below,

```
<input type="email" autocomplete="on" name="email"/>
```

The **autocomplete="on"** is giving the suggestion of email id's which I have entered previously in Chrome, Edge and Brave but not in Mozilla Firefox. Am I missing anything? or Do I need to do anything specifically for Firefox?

Comment: Is the browser's setting off? I think it's under 'Privacy'. (Not sure if there's a setting for email.)

Comment: @wazz Brower's Setting? You mean do I need to turn on anything on browser?

Comment: You might, not sure.

Comment: From the docs when `autocomplete` equals `"on"`, "[the] browser is allowed to automatically complete the input. No guidance is provided as to the type of data expected in the field, so the browser may use its own judgment." In other words, is there a reason you're not using `autocomplete="email"`?

Comment: Follow up on Brendan's comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete

Comment: @BrendanBond I tried with `autocomplete="email"` but still no luck.

Comment: if setting of firefox don't seems to work then you can try this code.
https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-feather-vwl6v?file=/index.html

Comment: @wazz Let me go through the document which you have sent..

Comment: @AashirAzeem The demo is working in Mozilla Firefox. Let me try this on my project. Thank you.

Comment: @AashirAzeem As per your solution, am able to resolve the issue. Thank you.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, `<input type="email" autocomplete="on" name="email"/>` autocompletes with my email address in Firefox.